# how to create a predicted line in a scatter plot

Tags: r

If someone could also tell me how I can work out what the equation for the line I currently have is as well, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `abline` function

```
abline(1,1)
```

The first argument is the intercept and the second is the slope.

Comment: thanks, that was simple. Do you also know how I can work out the value for my line of best fit?